# How to slow down a video and its audio by 20% using FFMPEG or HandBrakeCLI?

Tags: ffmpeg, handbrake

I am trying to slow down a video+audio a little bit, using this FFMpeg [command](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video):

```
ffmpeg.exe -i video.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]yadif,framerate=30,setpts=1.2*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=0.8[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -vsync vfr -vcodec h264_qsv out.mp4
```

but this command gives lots of warnings like this:

> [mp4 @ 00000194a7089040] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0;
>   previous: 2002, current: 2002; changing to 2003. This may result in
>   incorrect timestamps in the output file.

[image: Screenshot]
and the video and audio are out of sync on the out.mp4

How can I slow down a video and audio using FFMpeg or HandBrakeCLI ?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work well:

```
ffmpeg.exe -r 24 -i video.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]yadif[v];[0:a]atempo=0.8[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -vsync vfr -vcodec h264_qsv out.mp4
```

Source: #handbrake channel on Freenode, user BradleyS